# How to get a sub items header and value from listview

Tags: listview, vb6

I am using n number of column in listview, If i click any one of the sub items, that subitems should reflect in the textbox with column header.

For Example

ListView

```
1, 2 ........ n (Header)
001 Rajan ...... 50 (Values)
003 Vijayan...... 20
......
```

If i click the subitem 2 of 001 cell means it should display rajan in the textbox with header in label

Expected Output

```
Label1.caption = 2
text1.text = Rajan
```

Comment: Once again, there is no need to put "Need VB6 code help" at the bottom of every question as that is implied in the tags and the very fact that your asking a question. Please stop doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the subitem values. If you have a control array, you can do this in a loop:

```
Label1.caption = Item.Text
For Index = 1 To ListView.ColumnHeaders.Count - 1
  Text(Index).text = Item.SubItem(Index)
Next
```

`Item` being a reference to the selected row.

Comment: A `For`/`Next` loop on the ColumnHeaders collection. I've updated my answer to suit.